# Sorting content from a SharePoint list in an Infopath Form (2007)

Tags: infopath, forms-services, sorting

*Important note*: Version used is Infopath 2007 ans MOSS Enterprise (2007) with Enterprise features activated.

We have a form were you have to select a value. (Location)
Based on that value, you will have to fill in certain fields in Infopath.No issue so far.

Below this form, we would like to show the data that was already entered for that value location).
I created a data connection to a SharePoint List, and added a repeating table using the information from the SharePoint list.
This works, except that is is sorted on ID, ascending. This means that the oldest entries will show up at the top of that list. 
We would like to reverse the sorting and **show the most recent entries at the top**.

Only solutions without Visual Studio :-)

Thanks

@patman2520

Answer (score 0):

Change the sorting in the view of the SharePoint List from where you retrieve the values like described in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120920015905/http://joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/sharepoint/519-sort-order-a-dropdown-list-in-ms-infopath-without-programming.html) article.

Edit: Sorting is not supported with InfoPath 2007. But there is a workaround using the owssvr.dll - [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203231056/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/infopath/archive/2007/01/15/populating-form-data-from-sharepoint-list-views.aspx) is a good article on how to do this and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms478653%28v=office.14%29) is the parameter list (SortField).

hope this helps

Comment: Andreas,
yes it is described on that article, but if this only applies when you open the form in Infopath client, and not when you use the Forms service.

Answer (score 0):

You sort to belong to which kind of column on the repeating table.

1. go to Manage Data Connection
2. select Modify which connect template you add on repeating table.
3. on select fields, you can select which field to sort by ascending/descending.
4. apply and see sort on the repeating table following.